# Failed to resolve library in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to add a third party library in gradle. It is showing following error:

[image]

Here is my gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.attendme.io"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.4" //1.4.1
        //multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/kandy-1.6.160.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPicker:v1.0.10'


}
```

When I was searching about this problem I found some solutions but they weren't working for me. How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add 2 maven repositories.

So make sure your build.gradle(Project) includes this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and this goes in your build.gradle(app)

```
compile 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPicker:v1.0.10'
```

Comment: my build.gradle contains this repository : jcenter()

Comment: @Dhaval that is fine. You can leave it there and add the mavens below it

Comment: Thank you. The problem is solved. But I have one question. Should I always include this 2 mavens when I want to add third party library ?

Comment: @Dhaval no, it depends on what library you are importing. Most libraries can get just from `jcenter()`. If you need anything special like a specific maven url then they will tell you in their README on the library's website

Comment: Why doesn't android studio automatically add it beforehand?

Comment: Thank you @TimCastelijns this helped me to find the issue of integrating the 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1):

You should also add repositories to your build.gradle. Put those repositories in your `repositories` tag. Put those above the `android` tag.

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

We will use cwac-camera for take a picture. And get library from [enter link jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/)

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}

dependencies {
      compile 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPicker:v1.0.10'
}
```

Add permission for Camera, External Storage,Also Runtime permission for android6. For more information read offical [documentation](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPicker)

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```